# Magento 2 Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to __construct() must be an instance of Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context

Tags: magento2

In Magento 2.2, I have create a module and there I am getting this error.

> Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to __construct() must be an
>   instance of Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context, instance of
>   Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager given

My file path `app\code\Namespace\Modulename\Block\Adminhtml\Exporter\Edit\Tab\Form.php`

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\Modulename\Block\Adminhtml\Exporter\Edit\Tab;

class Form extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Generic implements \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Tab\TabInterface
{
    protected $exporter;

    public function __construct(
       \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
       \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
       \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory,
       \Raveinfosys\Orderexporter\Model\Exporter $exporter,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->exporter = $exporter;
        $this->_formFactory = $formFactory;

        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $formFactory, $data);
    }
```

They are showing error at

> public function __construct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, Magento caches constructor in `var/generation` folder, so if you clear the `var/generation` content then Magento will regenerate the interceptor.

```
rm -rf var/generation var/di
```

> Clearing `var/generation and var/di` could fix this issue.

Comment: I think it's always better to post complete error message, because there might be a possibility that you have some kind of typo mistake and that's why you're getting this error. Well, in short if the above solution doesn't work for you then post your error message!